# Subset matrix where any element satisfies condition

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix like

```
bar <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5)
rownames(bar)<- letters[1:5]
colnames(bar)<- LETTERS[1:5]
bar
          A          B           C          D          E
a 0.2584448  0.7749999  2.87730628 -0.6975622 -0.1932791
b 0.1103942 -1.6934814  1.93550788 -0.3174811  0.8109865
c 3.1351451 -0.3576796 -0.04163874  0.3428915  0.7812248
d 1.8645636  0.1902946 -1.08881511  1.9995945 -1.0550882
e 1.5714962  1.1754796 -1.19862113  0.4539959  0.6764810
```

And I want to pop this into circlize, but only for elements of the matrix where the value is > 1

Is there any way to limit this matrix to only cells that satisfy a condition like that, while maintaining the row and column names?

Comment: `which(bar > 1, arr.ind = TRUE)` will keep the row names and give you the matrix indices for the values.  Other than that you can use a logical matrix `bar > 1`

Answer (score 0):

You could replace with `NA`

```
bar[!bar>1]<-NA
```

Comment: I tried this approach and was running in 
    "to new columns would leave holes after existing columns"

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to remove values less than 1, you can do:

```
bar[bar < 1] = 0
chordDiagram(bar)
```

[image]

If you still want to keep the positions for these values (keep the space for these values while not showing them), you need to set the colors of these values to white with full transparency. E.g:

```
col_bar = bar
col_bar[bar >= 1] = "#FF000080"
col_bar[bar < 1] = "#FFFFFF00"
chordDiagram(bar, col = col_bar)
```

[image]